# Get AUTO INCREMENT ID for inserted element using ContentProviderOperation

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert element from the StackOverFlow web service :

```js
operations.add((ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(TagProvider.CONTENT_URI))
                        .withValue(TagTable.COLUMN_ID,i)
                        .withValue(TagTable.COLUMN_DISPLAY, currentTag.getName())
                        .withValue(TagTable.COLUMN_NB_OCCURRENCES,currentTag.getCount())
                        .build()) ;
```

What I want to know is what argument should I use as a second argument of the first withValue method, because when I use i (i is the counter of a for loop), I get this error :

```js
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): Process: fr.isima.android.tp3, PID: 3066
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.text.TextUtils.join(TextUtils.java:298)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at fr.isima.android.tp3.ui.BookAdapter.getView(BookAdapter.java:55)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-31 14:34:16.539: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-31 14:34:58.938: E/SQLiteLog(3109): (1555) abort at 12 in [INSERT INTO tag(nb_occurrences,display,_id) VALUES (?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: tag._id
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109): Error inserting nb_occurrences=816449 display=javascript _id=1
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: tag._id (code 1555)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at fr.isima.android.tp3.provider.TagProvider.insert(TagProvider.java:56)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:240)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.content.ContentProvider.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:1712)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:287)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:377)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:1244)
03-31 14:34:58.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(3109):  at fr.isima.android.tp3.service.DataFetchingService$TestThread.run(DataFetchingService.java:126)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109): FATAL EXCEPTION: test
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109): Process: fr.isima.android.tp3, PID: 3109
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109): android.database.SQLException: Failed to insert row into content://fr.isima.android.tp3.provider.TagProvider/tags
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at fr.isima.android.tp3.provider.TagProvider.insert(TagProvider.java:66)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:240)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at android.content.ContentProvider.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:1712)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:287)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:377)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:1244)
03-31 14:34:59.012: E/AndroidRuntime(3109):  at fr.isima.android.tp3.service.DataFetchingService$TestThread.run(DataFetchingService.java:126)
03-31 14:34:59.060: E/gralloc_goldfish(933): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 288 x 288, usage 333
03-31 14:34:59.061: E/(933): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=288, h=288) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
03-31 14:34:59.065: E/BufferQueueProducer(1244): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
03-31 14:34:59.068: E/ActivityManager(1244): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 288x288
03-31 14:37:24.259: E/CheckinTask(1730): SSL error, attempting time correction: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
03-31 14:37:24.736: E/CheckinTask(1730): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642): Service com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.http.f@f4c18e9 that was originally bound here
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.http.f@f4c18e9 that was originally bound here
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1072)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:966)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1768)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.e.<init>(SourceFile:94)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:234)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:196)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService.onCreate(SourceFile:1172)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2731)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1361)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-31 14:37:34.955: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642): null
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.http.f@f4c18e9 that was originally bound here
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1072)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:966)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1768)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.e.<init>(SourceFile:94)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:234)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.<init>(SourceFile:196)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService.onCreate(SourceFile:1172)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2731)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1361)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-31 14:37:34.984: E/StrictMode(1642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661): [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2139)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2115)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:658)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.am.<init>(SourceFile:47)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.b(SourceFile:162)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:80)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-31 14:37:35.204: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661): [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2139)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2115)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:658)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.am.<init>(SourceFile:47)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.a.a(SourceFile:65)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.c.a(SourceFile:39)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:67)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:39)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupAccountNotifierService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:76)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-31 14:37:35.498: E/Backup(1661):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-31 14:45:11.498: E/ActivityThread(1642): Service com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.http.f@2ca00e59 that was originally bound here
03-31 14:45:11.498: E/ActivityThread(1642): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.http.f@2ca00e59 that was originally bound here
03-31 14:45:11.498: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1072)
03-31 14:45:11.498: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:966)
03-31 14:45:11.498: E/ActivityThread(1642):  at
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like it says "UNIQUE constraint failed: tag._id Error inserting nb_occurrences=816449 display=javascript _id=1" It seems that you are trying to insert record with id = 1 while the record with same id already exists. id is a primary key and it should be unique.

Comment: Yes I understood that user1991679, but I don't know how to solve this problem, this is why I'm asking for the correct second argument of my first withvalue method call, do you have an idea ? Basically I guess that this argument should be the last row id+1, but how to get it ?

Comment: I do believe that you should not add id value at all, and you can retrieve it from content provider after you insert new record. i.e. content provider will insert record then retrieve a new record id and then you can access it.

Comment: Ok, so I should delete the line .withValue(TagTable.COLUMN_ID,i) ?

Comment: It depends on what you whant to do. If you need to know id you should either generate it somehow before inserting to make sure it's unique (for example get last row's id and add 1 to it) or get the id after inserting new record.

Comment: Ok, how to get the last row's ID ? Actually I just want to insert the elements correctly and to respect the unique ID constraint

Comment: If you don't need id for later use you can just delete this line. As "id" is a primary key it's value will be generated authomatically on insert when it's empty.